# Used Cursor inside cursor for update it is showing o rows effected, logic is working when i tried manually

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

stored procedure
Used Cursor inside cursor for update it is showing 0 rows effected, logic is working when i tried manually, declaring and closing done properly.

any changes do i need to do
or any alternatives than cursor.

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POS_Discount_Report]
    @OutletId INT  = NULL,  
    @FromDate DATE = NULL,    
    @ToDate DATE = NULL,
    @DiscountPercent  DECIMAL = NULL  
AS
begin           
        SELECT  @CutOffInvoiceAmount = AVG(InvoiceAmount) FROM POS_SalesReceiptMaster WHERE StampDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

        DECLARE Receipt_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Id FROM  POS_SalesReceiptMaster WHERE StampDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND InvoiceAmount <= @CutOffInvoiceAmount
        OPEN Receipt_cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM Receipt_cursor
                INTO @ReceiptId

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN
                DECLARE Item_cursor CURSOR FOR
                SELECT Id FROM Updated_SalesReceiptItems WHERE ReceiptId = @ReceiptId
                OPEN Item_cursor
                FETCH NEXT FROM Item_cursor
                INTO @ID


                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @Percentage = Percentage, @ItemPrice = Price FROM 
                    Updated_SalesReceiptItems WHERE Id = @ID
                    IF @Percentage = 5
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @UpdatePercentage = Tax5   FROM   Updated_Master 
                        Where Percentage = @DiscountPercent  
                    END
                    ELSE
                                        BEGIN
                            @UpdatePercentage = 5
                    END



                    UPDATE Updated_SalesReceiptItems
                            SET  ProductId   =   Product.ProductId,
                                 Actualprice =   Product.Actualprice,
                                 Quantity    =   Product.Qty,
                                 ProductName =   Product.ProductName,
                                 unit        =   Product.unit,
                                 CategoryName=   Product.CategoryName,
                                 Percentage=     Product.Percentage,
                                 Amount =        Product.Amount FROM
                            (SELECT TOP 1  PM.ProductId, ProductCode, 

                           dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(ProductId,@OutletId) 
                                     AS                                                            
                                       Actualprice, 
                                (CASE WHEN ( dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId) != 0)
                                    THEN (@ItemPrice  / dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId)) 
                                    ELSE 0
                                END)  AS  Qty,
                                ProductName, Unit, CategoryName, @UpdatePercentage AS Percentage,
                                dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId) * (@UpdatePercentage/100) AS TaxAmount
                            FROM dbo.Products_Master PM
                                INNER JOIN ProductCategory_Master  CM ON  PM.CategoryId = CM.CategoryId
                                INNER JOIN tax_master  TM ON  PM.TaxId = TM.Id
                             WHERE (@ItemPrice) % nullif(dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId),0) = 0
                                AND Percentage = @UpdatePercentage) Product
                    WHERE Id = @ID
                   end



                FETCH NEXT FROM Item_cursor
                INTO @ID
                 END
                CLOSE Item_cursor;
                DEALLOCATE Item_cursor;


                FETCH NEXT FROM Receipt_cursor
                INTO @ReceiptId
                END
        CLOSE Receipt_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE Receipt_cursor;

END
```

Comment: There's MANY alternatives to using a cursor, looping through temporary tables, table variables, etc.  But looking at your script it could probably be converted into a set based query (as the logic isn't overly complex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is pretty scrappy, and probably won't work without some fixing, but it should give you the general pattern for doing all of this in a single query?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE POS_Discount_Report (
    @OutletId INT  = NULL,  
    @FromDate DATE = NULL,    
    @ToDate DATE = NULL,
    @DiscountPercent  DECIMAL = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CutOffInvoiceAmount NUMERIC(19,2); --?? seems to be missing from original procedure
    SELECT @CutOffInvoiceAmount = AVG(InvoiceAmount) FROM POS_SalesReceiptMaster WHERE StampDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate; --What happens if one or both of these is NULL?

    --CTEs
    WITH Receipt AS (
        SELECT Id FROM POS_SalesReceiptMaster WHERE StampDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND InvoiceAmount <= @CutOffInvoiceAmount),
    Item AS (
        SELECT Id FROM Updated_SalesReceiptItems s INNER JOIN Receipt r ON s.ReceiptId = r.Id),
    PercentQuery AS (
        SELECT i.Id, u.[Percentage], u.Price FROM Updated_SalesReceiptItems u INNER JOIN Item i ON u.Id = i.Id),
    UpdatePercent AS (
        SELECT p.Id, p.[Percentage], p.Price, CASE WHEN p.[Percentage] = 5 THEN u.Tax5 ELSE 5 END AS UpdatePercentage FROM PercentQuery p INNER JOIN Updated_Master u ON u.[Percentage] = @DiscountPercent)
    UPDATE 
        u
    SET  
        ProductId = pm.ProductId,
        Actualprice = dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(ProductId, @OutletId),
        Quantity = 
            CASE 
                WHEN (dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId) != 0) 
                THEN (@ItemPrice  / dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId)) 
                ELSE 0
            END,
        ProductName = pm.ProductName,
        unit = pm.unit, --not sure on the alias here, as it's missing in the original query
        CategoryName = pm.CategoryName,
        [Percentage] = u.UpdatePercentage,
        Amount = dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, ProductId) * (u.UpdatePercentage / 100) --although this was TaxAmount originally??! 
    FROM
        dbo.Products_Master pm
        INNER JOIN ProductCategory_Master cm ON cm.CategoryId = pm.CategoryId
        INNER JOIN tax_master tm ON tm.Id = pm.TaxId
        INNER JOIN UpdatePercent up ON up.Id = pm.Id
        INNER JOIN Updated_SalesReceiptItems u ON u.Id = up.Id
    WHERE 
        (p.Price) % NULLIF(dbo.fn_Get_ProductPrice_By_Outlet(@OutletId, pm.ProductId), 0) = 0
        AND [Percentage] = UpdatePercentage;
END;
```

Basically, I use nested common-table expressions to perform the same action as your original cursors, but these are now set-based.  This means I can JOIN the results to the table to be updated and perform all of the updates in a single hit.

I almost certainly got some of this wrong, as I could see a number of parts in your original query that just seemed incorrect?

Comment: vry Thank you sir, please let me check Richard Hansell

Comment: Yikes, I didn't realise this was intentional.  It's not impossible, but it does become tricky now.  You would essentially need to change that entire UPDATE statement back to how it was originally (as a subquery), then update the subquery...

Comment: Also, your original method was to UPDATE the TOP 1 record, but you have no ORDER BY clause in that script, so it would be an entirely arbitrary update?  Without seeing the actual data being used it's hard to comment further...

Comment: i think problem is with update sub query(orginal), still showing 0 rows effected.

Comment: working fine. increased performance and got result by using script you written, I think  
 that type of updatation in cursor is problem in my script.